# How to load thousands of records from local database to recyclerview without blocking UI using ROOM library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-room, android-threading

I am using local database to load records on recyclerview the problem is the size of records its about six thousand and when I click  to open or show those records in recyclerview my device stuck for a few seconds a blank screen appear and when few seconds pass it appear and show records. Is there a way to load thousands of records or data on recyclerview without blockage of UI? please let me know thanks

Comment: use paging library https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/LivePagedListBuilder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy & paste this method to your Activity / Baseactivity. and call this after `yourRecyclerview.setAdapter(YourAdapter)`

```
public void PagginationRecyclerView(RecyclerView rv) {
   rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            int total = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            int currentLastItem = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (currentLastItem == total - 1) {
                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "Load Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Request to Database to load more data
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this method will reload more data from db only when scroll reach to the last -1 visible item in your recyclerview. (you've to modify & replace the toast message).

there is another library also available called, SwipeToRefresh you can find this on github.

please appriciate by up-voting if it helped you.

Comment: could you please also share sqlite query to load limited number of records at a time !

Comment: Better to Load the limited data (suppose 50 row or entries from db) and show. Than again load next 50 entries. 
⚠️ loading whole data will impact on the speed of your app and will create memory issue too.

Comment: I wish i could share the source code for your problem but unfortunately  i don’t have now.